# How can I know the username and password if I only have a .sql file

Tags: java, sql, rest, servlets, jdbc

I am attempting to use Java servlet to access an existing .sql file via JDBC. The aim is to develop a RESTful web service to insert, edit, update, delete the data in the database.

As this is the first time I do it, I am confused by one question:

As I am to set up JDBC connection, how do we know the username, password and driver information? They are not shown in the .sql file I have.

Comment: JDBC is used to access a database, not a sql file. I guess you're supposed to set up the database yourself, and thus choose the user and the password you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql by default username is "root" without password

Comment: NEVER use the default authentication!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using JDBC to connect to the database, then you can provide credentials, together with other database specific data in a separate dataSource property file. Take a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html